# r raster brick sum values in the cells determined by two different rasters, how to speed up calculations

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm working with climate data files with daily data so for most years 365 rasters in a brick. I want to sum over the value in files for subsets of days - say day x to day y. This can be done with stackApply. I've created some code below that generates some rasters, creates a brick and applies stackApply using specific values for x and y, 1 and 3.

What I need however is for x and y to taken from two raster layers. In the code below they are called raster.start and raster.end. Below the first set of code I have a second set that works but is slow.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
s <- stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r), min = -10*i, max = 10))))
raster.start <- setValues(r, sample(2, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
raster.end <- raster.start + 3
rasterb <- brick(s)

indices <- format(as.Date(names(rasterb), format = "layer.%d"), format = "%d")
indices <- c(1,1,1,1,1)

datasum.all <- stackApply(rasterb, indices, fun = sum)
datasum.sub1 <- stackApply(rasterb[[c(1:3)]], indices, fun = sum)
```

The idea is to step through the rows and columns of the start and end raster to subset the brick  and operate on it. Here's the code I developed to do this.

```
raster.out <- r
for (i in 1:nrow(r)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(r)){
    start <- raster.start[[1]][i,j] # get the starting day
    end <- raster.end[[1]][i,j] # get the ending day
    raster.out[i,j] <- sum(rasterb[[start:end]][i,j])
  }
}
```

However, even for this toy example the computation time is slow. It took about 1.3 minutes to complete. I tried replacing some of the code with functions, as follows but it had no effect on the time to completion. Any advice on how to speed up this process greatly appreciated.

```
startEnd <- function(raster.start, raster.end, i,j) {
  start <- raster.start[i,j] # get the starting day
  end <- raster.end[i,j] # get the ending day
  return(c(start,end))
}

rasterOutValue <- function(rasterb, i, j, startEnd){
  return(sum(rasterb[[startEnd]][i,j]))
}

for (i in 1:nrow(raster.in1)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(raster.in1)){
    raster.out[i,j] <-rasterOutValue(rasterb, i, j, startEnd(raster.start, raster.end, i,j))
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `*apply`-function?

Comment: I'm not very conversant with those functions. I did do some research in stack overflow but didn't find anything that looked similar to what I want to do.

Comment: This code uses stackApply and is about 3 times faster - `for (i in 1:nrow(raster.in1)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(raster.in1)){
    datasum.sub1 <- stackApply(rasterb[[start:end]], indices, fun = sum)
  }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Your example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
set.seed(88)
b <- stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r), min = -10*i, max = 10))))
r.start <- setValues(r, sample(2, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
r.end <- raster.start + 3
```

First an improved version of your example that works, but is too slow. The below is considerably faster, but still rather slow.

```
raster.out <- r
for (i in 1:ncell(r)){
    start <- raster.start[i] # get the starting day
    end <- raster.end[i] # get the ending day
    raster.out[i] <- sum(rasterb[i][start:end])
}
```

That brings the time down from 74 to 5 seconds for me. But you should never loop over cells, that is always going to be too slow. Instead, you can do (in 0.04 seconds for me):

```
s <- stack(r.start, r.end, b)
x <- calc(s, fun=function(x) sum(x[(x[1]:x[2])+2]))
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 3.6, 1.8  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : -129.5758, 30.31813  (min, max)
```

And that seems to be correct

```
a <- s[1]
a
#     layer.1.1 layer.2.1 layer.1.2 layer.2.2  layer.3   layer.4   layer.5
#[1,]         1         4 -1.789974  2.640807 4.431439 -23.09203 -5.688119    

fun <- function(x) sum(x[(x[1]:x[2])+2])
fun(a)
#[1] -17.80976
x[1]
#[1] -17.80976
```

`calc` is to Raster objects what `apply` is to matrices. (that is why it is called `app` in `terra`.

The place to start is to first write a function that does what you want with a vector.

```
x <- 1:10
test1 <- function(start, end, values) {
    mean(values[start:end]) 
}
test1(2, 5, x)
test1(5, 8, x)
```

`calc` only takes one argument, so a function like this

```
test2 <- function(values) {
    # the +2 to skip the first two elements in the computation
    start <- values[1] + 2
    end <- values[2] + 2
    mean(values[start:end]) 
}

test2(c(2, 5, x))
test2(c(5, 8, x))
```

And a more concise version

```
test3 <- function(v) {
    mean(v[ (v[1]:v[2])+2 ] ) 
}
 test3(c(2, 5, x))
 #[1] 3.5
 test3(c(5, 8, x))
 #[1] 6.5
```

Second addition (and reminder to always check with NA values!). `test3` breaks when one of the indices (start and end) are `NA` (it is OK if the others are `NA`)

```
test3(c(NA, 5, x))
#Error in v[1]:v[2] : NA/NaN argument
```

So we need a function that catches these

```
test4 <- function(v) {
    if (any(is.na(v[1:2]))) {
        NA
    } else {
        mean(v[ (v[1]:v[2])+2 ] ) 
    }
}

test4(c(NA, 5, x))
#[1] NA
test4(c(1, 5, x))
#[1] 3
```

Typically "start" and "end" will both be `NA` at the same time, so a simpler version that should also work could be

```
test5 <- function(v) {
    if (is.na(v[1])) {
        NA
    } else {
        mean(v[ (v[1]:v[2])+2 ] ) 
    }
}
```

This approach with `calc` might be slow as it turns a RasterBrick into a RasterStack with 365 + 2 layers. That considerabley slows downs reading the data. So you could try this approach with `overlay` instead (here using `sum` again)

```
f <- function(i, v) {
    j <- !is.na(i[,1])
    r <- rep(NA, nrow(i))
    x <- cbind(i[j,,drop=FALSE], v[j,,drop=FALSE])
    r[j] <- apply(x, 1, function(y) sum(y[ (y[1]:y[2])+2 ] )) 
    r
}
cal <-stack(r.start, r.end)
x <- overlay(cal, b, fun= f, recycle=FALSE)
x
#class      : RasterLayer 
# ...
#values     : -129.5758, 30.31813  (min, max)
```

You can speed up the algorithm by writing it in Rcpp/C++

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('std::vector<double> gtemp(NumericMatrix cal, NumericMatrix wth) {
    std::vector<double> out(cal.nrow(), NAN);
    for (int i=0; i<cal.nrow(); i++) {
      if (!std::isnan(cal(i,0))){
         NumericVector v = wth(i,_);
         size_t start = cal(i,0)-1;
         size_t end = cal(i,1);
         out[i] = std::accumulate(v.begin()+start, v.begin()+end, 0.0);
      }  
    }
    return out;
}')

x <- overlay(cal, b, fun=gtemp, recycle=FALSE)
```

---

And here is how you can do this with `terra` (version >= 0.6-14) and the `rapp` (range-apply) method.

Example data

```
library(terra)
d <- rast(nrows=100, ncols=100, nl=5)
rstart <- rast(d, nlyr=1)
nc <- ncell(d) 
set.seed(88)
values(d) <- t(sapply(1:5, function(i) runif(nc, min = -10*i, max = 10)))
values(rstart) <- sample(2, nc, replace=TRUE)
rend <- rstart + 3
```

Solution

```
idx <- c(rstart, rend)
z <- rapp(d, idx, "sum")
z  
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 100, 100, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 3.6, 1.8  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#data source : memory 
#names       :      lyr1 
#min values  : -184.6918 
#max values  :  34.93876
```

Comment: A bit more concise is an understatement. I'm not sure this does what I want. I need the following. For each 1/2 degree pixel, get the r.start and r.end values. Use these to identify the day numbers over which to sum in b. My real b has 365*10 layers (plus a couple more for leap years). I want to create a new raster that sums the values of b for the same pixel. And then divide by 10 to get the average value for the 10 year period. I realize that this detail was not in the original example. The real world explanation for what I'm trying to estimate is growing degree days in a crop calendar.

Comment: I believe that is what this does. Except replace "sum" by "mean" --- I extended my answer trying to show how to get there (or elsewhere)

Comment: While studying your additions (which are very helpful!) I tried running your code with my data.  Here's the stack code - `s <- stack(croppingCalendar_plantstart, croppingCalendar_plantend, gdd)`; and the results from  `x <- calc(s, fun = function(x) sum(x[(x[1]:x[2]) + 2]))
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function` Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I bet that is because of NA values. See the updated answer for a solution

Comment: And there are lots of NAs. The rasters have values only where there is land. Can I mask somehow and have the function run over only the pixels with land? In the meantime I'll try your new function!

Comment: Here's what I ran. s is the stack that has both the start and end rasters as well as the gdd stack.  `x <- calc(s, fun = function(v) { if (is.na(v[1])) {
+         NA
+       } else {   mean(v[ (v[1]:v[2]) + 2 ] ) 
+       }})` After 14.48 hours I got one layer out. I'm also expecting values that are in the 200-500 range. I think I need to go back to sum. But do you have any suggestions about speeding up the process?

Comment: Perhaps use overlay instead (see appended aswer)

Comment: I've been doing some experiments with what you appended. cal is not defined explicitly. I though it might be `stack(start, end)` but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: it is, fixed it.

Comment: I had sort of figured that out in the meantime. One change have made is to replace mean with sum. The sum is over each year; the mean should be of the sum of the means. Now here's the next issue. It appears to do only the first year. A typical b has 3652 layers. 365 per year except for leap years. When I run your function over the full b or over a subset   `b_sub <- subset(b, 1:365)` the layer is identical to the one from the full b. That turns out to be ok because I can use the layers for each year, but is there a way to modify the function to get the sum by year and the mean of the sums?

Comment: I added one more variant. As for the 10 year period, yes that can be done, but that becomes a different question